# what is the best method to create report using java

Tags: java, db2

I will be creating a sales report using java my source is db2 database i was wondering what is the best method to create(fastest,efficient)?
it will be a comma seperated

Comment: you can use https://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports is a cool tool to create different kind of reports in different formats. It can also be integrated into NetBeans and Eclipse. So just design the report, test it and if you are fine, use the java-libraries coming with Jasper to run your report in Java. The library also has the possibility to hand over parameters.